# Обновление виджета PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Идея проста, по нажатию на кнопку должен добавляться `label`. Но он не отображается, потому что, насколько я понял, окно уже отрисовалось. Как его можно обновить?

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.vvbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea()
        self.area = QWidget()
        self.label_box = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button = QPushButton('button')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.create_label)

        self.area.setLayout(self.label_box)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.area)
        self.vvbox.addWidget(self.scrollarea)
        self.vvbox.addWidget(self.button)

    def create_label(self):
        label = QLabel('text')
        self.label_box.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте [setWidgetResizable(True)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop):

```
...
self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.area)
self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
...
```